# Update deep child node html c# HtmlNode

Tags: c#, html

My html code:

```
<div>
    <a href="someurl">
        Some Link
        <span title="some text">xxx</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Like you see, the **span** tag is a deep child of **div** tag!

I tried to find **span** node in **div** node by ChildNodes but HtmlNode gave me only lv1 node like **a** node, so, I could not interact with **span**

How can I update this **span** title?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "update?"  Are you trying to manipulate the span using C# code?  Are you using Linq to XML or some other tool? How do you intend to uniquely identify the span?

Comment: Hi, @maccettura, please review again, I just updated my code!

Comment: Hi @RobertHarvey, I want to replace this span title (some text) by another string

Comment: @RobertHarvey I got your idea but my html dom have dynamic number of level, so, I think it's low possible to detect where any child is

Comment: How do you propose to do that without having an id on the span?  Do you have a way to identify the span?  If this is server-side, don't you already control the html anyway?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I will give you the way to detect this span, will you give to me a new div with new span then? :D

Comment: I suspect that, if you have a way to get the span into a first-class C# object, modifying it will become obvious.

Comment: With HtmlNode, I can get a List of this span. I can change it's attr, but I can't bind it back to div like something supported lazy loading

Comment: How are you generating the span in the first place?  What is HtmlNode?  Is that the HtmlNode from HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: I will talk to you when my problem gone :D Sorry, may my English is not good! Thank you, your answers were very bright

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery and get decedents by simply 
     $('div a span')

Comment: I want to do it in server side